# integration over unit ball

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Can anyone give me some explanation about the following fact? Many thanks!

Let $B$ be the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^d$, $d\ge 1$. Then 
$$\int_{\mathbf{z}\in B}\frac{1}{|\mathbf{z}|^c}\,\mathrm{d} \mathbf{z}<\infty$$
if and only if $c<d$.

Comment: If you transform the integral into spherical coordinates, you get an $\int_0^1 r^{d-1-c}\,dr$. That converges if and only if $d-1-c > -1 \iff d > c$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can employ a scaling argument. First, assume that $c\ge d$, and find (with $r<1$)
$$
  \int_B \frac{1}{|z|^c}\,dz\ge\int_{rB}\frac{1}{|z|^c}\,dz=\int_B\frac{r^d}{r^c|w|^c}\,dw=r^{d-c}\int_B\frac{1}{|w|^c}\,dw=r^{d-c}\int_B\frac{1}{|z|^c}\,dz
$$
using the change of variables $z=rw$, $dz=r^d\,dw$. If the integral is finite, the first inequality is strict, but $r^{d-c}\ge1$, so you get a contradiction.

If $c<d$, let instead $A_n$ be the shell $2^{-n}B\setminus2^{-n-1}B$ and employ the change of variables $z=2w$:
$$
  \int_{A_n}\frac{1}{|z|^c}\,dz=\int_{A_{n+1}}\frac{2^d}{2^c|w|^c}\,dw=2^{d-c}\int_{A_{n+1}}\frac{1}{|z|^c}\,dz
$$
so by induction
$$
  \int_{A_n}\frac{1}{|z|^c}\,dz=2^{n(c-d)}\int_{A_0}\frac{1}{|z|^c}\,dz.
$$
Now $B=\{0\}\cup\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty A_n$ (this is a disjoint union), so
$$
  \int_B\frac1{|z|^d}\,dz
  =\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_{A_n}\frac1{|z|^d}\,dz
  =\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^{n(c-d)}\int_{A_0}\frac{1}{|z|^c}\,dz<\infty,
$$
since $\int_{A_0}\frac{1}{|z|^c}\,dz$ is clearly finite and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^{n(c-d)}$ converges.

(You may think this argument ridiculously involved for something that is easily solved by direct calculation, but this sort of scaling argument is frequently useful in situations that are not amenable to direct calculation. And note that there is very little actual *computation* going on in this argument.)

Comment: The second argument applies also when $c<d$, but now the sum diverges, so the integral over $B$ is infinite. But the first argument seems more instructive in this case, and sets the stage for the second argument.